# get Linux Monitor resolution with C

Tags: c, gtk3, resolution

how can i get monitor resolution in **Fedora Linux** with **C**,
I need to know the screen size in my **GTK3 application** but I can't find a solution
Because I want to make a full screen software

And for this I need to know the screen size **in pixels**

How do desktops like gnome built with gtk find the screen size ?

I used this Code but it gave me an error :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short *get_screen_size(void)
{
    static unsigned short size[2];
    char *array[8];
    char screen_size[64];
    char* token = NULL;

    FILE *cmd = popen("xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/ {print $2}'", "r");

    if (!cmd)
        return 0;

    while (fgets(screen_size, sizeof(screen_size), cmd) != NULL);
    pclose(cmd);

    token = strtok(screen_size, "x\n");

    if (!token)
        return 0;

    for (unsigned short i = 0; token != NULL; ++i) {
        array[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "x\n");
    }
    size[0] = atoi(array[0]);
    size[1] = atoi(array[1]);
    size[2] = -1;

    return size;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned short *size = get_screen_size();

    printf("Screen resolution = %dx%d\n", size[0], size[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

when i run it :

```
sh: line 1: xdpyinfo: command not found
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: If it's a question about package providing xdpyinfo, then on one of redhat based os at my hand: `rpm -qf /usr/bin/xdpyinfo` says it's in `xorg-x11-utils`

Comment: i dont understand whats ! should i install this package to get the screen resolution?

Comment: my fedora windowing system in wayland not X11

Comment: Make it a bit more clear: Do you ask about compatibilty between (x)wayland and xorg/x11?

Comment: There were two questions, one related to 'xdpyinfo: command not found', and other one about screen size in gtk3. The answer about the package which contains xdpyinfo is above. On getting screen size in gtk3: - proper gdk functions are described in its own documentation.

Comment: My question was about getting the screen size in C language

Answer (score 1):

In [GTK3](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/) ([GDK3](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/) 3.22+), [`gdk_monitor_get_geometry`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/method.Monitor.get_geometry.html) can be used to populate a [`GdkRectangle`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/struct.Rectangle.html) structure with the width and height of a *monitor*.

Alternatively, there is [`gdk_monitor_get_workarea`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/method.Monitor.get_workarea.html), which functions much the same, but takes into consideration docks, panels, and other desktop components.

See also:

- [`gdk_window_fullscreen`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/method.Window.fullscreen.html) | [`gtk_window_fullscreen`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Window.fullscreen.html)
- [`gdk_window_fullscreen_on_monitor`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/method.Window.fullscreen_on_monitor.html) | [`gtk_window_fullscreen_on_monitor`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Window.fullscreen_on_monitor.html)
- [`gdk_window_unfullscreen`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/method.Window.unfullscreen.html) | [`gtk_window_unfullscreen`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Window.unfullscreen.html)

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void
activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default();
    int n_monitors = gdk_display_get_n_monitors(display);

    for (int nth = 0; nth < n_monitors; nth++) {
        GdkMonitor *monitor = gdk_display_get_monitor(display, nth);

        GdkRectangle geo;
        gdk_monitor_get_geometry(monitor, &geo);

        printf("(#%d) %-5s %-10s | Scale: %2d | %5dx%-5d | Position: %6dx%-6d%s\n",
                nth,
                gdk_monitor_get_manufacturer(monitor),
                gdk_monitor_get_model(monitor),
                gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor(monitor),
                geo.width,
                geo.height,
                geo.x,
                geo.y,
                gdk_monitor_is_primary(monitor) ? " (Primary)" : "");
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.example.monitorsize", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);

    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

Example output:

```
(#0) AOC   DVI-I-1    | Scale:  1 |  1920x1080  | Position:   1440x0      (Primary)
(#1) DEL   DP-1       | Scale:  1 |  1280x1024  | Position:   3360x0     
(#2) SAM   DVI-D-0    | Scale:  1 |  1440x900   | Position:      0x0
```

---

The (now deprecated) functions [`gdk_screen_width`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/type_func.Screen.width.html) and [`gdk_screen_height`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/type_func.Screen.height.html) retrieve the dimensions of the default *screen*, but this information is rather uninteresting when there are multiple monitors.

```
printf("%dx%d\n", gdk_screen_width(), gdk_screen_height());
```

```
4640x1080
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem here is that the `xdpyinfo` command was not found ( not installed ).**

The package that contains the `xdpyinfo` command on fedora is the `xorg-x11-utils` package.

To install the above package you can use the following command:

```
yum install xorg-x11-utils
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will install this package ,But after this, should this package be installed on every computer where my gtk software runs?

Comment: For example, if I want to run my software in Arch or Debian distribution

Comment: Yes, you need this command, so the command has to be installed in every system you want to use it., for debian like system you can use `apt-get install x11-utils` command.

Comment: thanks. How software like gnome have been able to get the size of the screen without needing this command? My only problem is that my software can take the screen size without needing additional packages

Comment: This could be another question, but in any case, in all system you can get the resolution of the screen if you know the device name with the command: `cat /sys/class/graphics/*/modes` or `cat /sys/class/graphics/*/virtual_size`, where at the place of the star ( `*` ), you put the name of the device.

Comment: You helped a lot
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the X11 library if you're using linux.

```
// Declare includes.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main (void)
{
// Declare variables.
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XWindowAttributes wa = {0};

// Get screen attributes.
    XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), &wa);

// Print values.
    printf("Width: %d\tHeight: %d\n", wa.width, wa.height);

// Exit program.
    return(0);
}
```

Keep in mind this is for systems with one screen only.

EDIT: You may need the package :`libX11-devel`